# Iwahori decomposition in group theory

Tags: group-theory

I am going through a book (Roberts and Schmidt, *Local Newforms for GSp(4)*), which states the following group decomposition. Let $F$ be a non-archimedean field, $\mathfrak{o}$ its ring of integers and $\mathfrak{p}$ its maximal ideal. Then, in terms of subgroups of $\mathrm{GSp}(4)$,
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
\mathfrak{o}&\mathfrak{o}&\mathfrak{o}&\mathfrak{o}\\
\mathfrak{p}^n&\mathfrak{o}&\mathfrak{o}&\mathfrak{o}\\
\mathfrak{p}^n&\mathfrak{o}&\mathfrak{o}&\mathfrak{o}\\
\mathfrak{p}^n&\mathfrak{p}^n&\mathfrak{p}^n&\mathfrak{o}
\end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
1& & & \\
\mathfrak{p}^n&1& & \\
\mathfrak{p}^n& &1& \\
\mathfrak{p}^n&\mathfrak{p}^n&\mathfrak{p}^n&1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
\mathfrak{o}^\times&&&\\
 &\mathfrak{o}&\mathfrak{o}&\\
 &\mathfrak{o}&\mathfrak{o}& \\
 & & &\mathfrak{o}^\times
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
\mathfrak{1}&\mathfrak{o}&\mathfrak{o}&\mathfrak{o}\\
 &\mathfrak{1}& &\mathfrak{o}\\
 & &\mathfrak{1}&\mathfrak{o}\\
 & &  &\mathfrak{1}
\end{array}
\right)
$$

where missing entries are zeros. I would like to understand this decomposition more generally, for I would like to apply that for other groups. Is there any general setting for this Iwahori factorization? (it seems similar to an $LU$ factorization, however is it always true and what are exactly the three groups appearing on the right?)

I found in this focument, right after (1.6.3) a form of the Iwahori factorization, however not all the terms are defined (for instance $A_\mathfrak{o}$).

Comment: It should work for reductive group over fields - see e.g. http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/courses/seminar-06b/macdonald.pdf lemma 1.5

Comment: @Pig Great reference, this is the precise king of statement I was expecting. However, does the same result hold for $\mathfrak{p}^n$ instead of $\mathfrak{p}$ in the Lemma 1.5, or is there something critical with the maximal ideal? (I mean replacing $\mathfrak{p}$ by $\mathfrak{p}^n$ in the definition of the Iwahori subgroup as well as in $\bar{N}(\mathfrak{p})$.)

Comment: It still works at higher level - also, thanks for crossposting this at MO, Marty's answer is cool :)